# Identify cartoon about a set of fairy/demon twins in a far future where the demon uses propaganda to take over the world

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I'm looking for a cartoon from the 70's (I believe) which is about a set of twins; one plump "fairy" and a skeletal "demon". The "fairy" has magic powers and ends up living a life of pleasure, while the "demon" flees and turns evil.

When the "demon" finds his new weapon in the ruins of the ancient world (roughly modern day) he plots to enslave the world; the weapon in question is a set of propaganda movies with Adolf Hitler.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you describe is at least vaguely similar to the animated movie *"[Wizards](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076929/)"*, which the [Wikipedia describes as](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_%28film%29)

> Wizards is a 1977 American animated post-apocalyptic science fantasy film about the battle between two wizards, one representing the forces of magic and one representing the forces of industrial technology. It was written, produced, and directed by Ralph Bakshi.

[image]

(Image credit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wizards_poster.jpg)

In the movie the brothers are wizards rather than fairies, thought the good wizards companions include a scantily clad, winged fairy. There is heavy use of World War II footage in various psychedelic mixes to show the evil armies on the march.

There are many images and YouTube segments (or the whole movie) available from the [search "animated movie wizards"](https://www.google.com/search?q=animated%20movie%20wizards), but Google doesn't know that they are copyright kosher so I have not copied any here.

---

I have always liked the movie though it is a bit corny in places. Many of my friends are not so happy about it, so I suppose it is a "so bad it's good" movie---a category that is highly personal in my experience.

Comment: [Avatar](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ralphbakshi/2312133762/)- the good brother, [Blackwolf](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141011015837/villains/images/thumb/e/e4/Blackwolf.jpg/300px-Blackwolf.jpg)- evil brother...twin sons of Delia, Queen of the fairies.

Comment: OK, I guess they're fairies.

Comment: Maybe fairy wizards? :)

Comment: That's the one. Thanks :-)